# How can I test for a significant difference here?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric

I would simply like to compare the frequency of two variables that come from the same sample. The variable longgain has the value 1 if a gain in the portfolio of an investor is held for longer than 200 days whereas the variable longloss has the value 1 if a loss is held for longer than 200 days.

My hypothesis is:
There are more investors holding onto losses compared to investors holding onto gains for longer than 200 days.

From what I have read I think that a nonparametric test for one sample is the correct choice here and since the data is binary the binomial test would fit? Could anyone confirm this please or point out if I made an error in my reasoning

The histogram of longloss looks like this:
[image]

Whereas the histogram of longgain looks like this:
[image]

The frequencies amount to the following
[image]

Comment: Why a hypothesis test?  Why do you think "significance" means something?  I'd concentrate on estimating (point and interval) the difference of interest.  But don't use a cutoff like 200 days.  Look at the whole time distribution.  And show histograms of **raw** data with 200 bins to see the whole data distribution.  Assess the degree to which time held changes.

Comment: Before we get to doing a hypothesis test, I am not sure about what is being measured. Are we talking about each investor's portfolio's total market value or its buy-and-hold return? Also,  there would be plenty of investors with gains over most recent 5 year period and losses over the last year. How is that type of situation included?